# vector programming : Not clear about the initialization of the vector

Tags: c++, stl, stdvector

I am having an issue with the usage for vector

consider the code that does the following:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    printf("%s\n","CreateNewVector");
    vector<int> *vector1 = createNewVector(5);
    if(vector1){
        delete vector1;
        vector1=NULL;
    }

    printf("%s\n","AddToVector");
    vector<int> vector2;
    if(AddToVector(vector2))
    {

    }
        if(vector1)
        {
            delete vector1;
            vector1 = NULL;
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Oddly it prints the following when createNewVector(5) is called!

```
CreateNewVector
Pushing createNewVector 5
Pushing createNewVector 4
Pushing createNewVector 3
Pushing createNewVector 2
Pushing createNewVector 1

0 0 0 0 0 5 4 3 2 1
```

Here is the code for CreateNewVector

```
vector<int> * createNewVector(int n) {
    // YOUR CODE HERE
    vector<int> *vector1 = new vector<int>(n);
    for (int i=n;i>0;--i)
    {
        printf("Pushing %s %d\n",__FUNCTION__,i);
        vector1->push_back(i);
    }
    printf("\n");


    for(auto it = vector1->begin(); it!=vector1->end();it++)
        printf("%d ",*it);
    printf("\n");
    return vector1;
}
```

In comparison, I  have another code (using AddToVector) that merely takes a vector by reference and merely adds to it using the same API

```
vector1->push_back(i);

Code for AddToVector
bool AddToVector(vector<int> &vector) {
    // YOUR CODE HERE
    int n = 5;
    for (int i=n;i>0;--i)
    {
        printf("Pushing %s %d\n",__FUNCTION__,i);
        vector.push_back(i);
    }
    printf("\n");


    for(auto it = vector.begin(); it!=vector.end();it++)
        printf("%d ",*it);

    printf("\n");
    return true;
}
```

I am clueless about the sequence that also has some redundant 0's

Now when I replace that code that takes a vector as a reference and kinda does the same, the output is clear and what is expected. 
The output is the following:
AddToVector

```
Pushing AddToVector 5
Pushing AddToVector 4
Pushing AddToVector 3
Pushing AddToVector 2
Pushing AddToVector 1

5 4 3 2 1
```

Comment: There is almost never a reason to create a vector dynamically like that.

Comment: Why are you using C I/O in a C++ program? A vector will manage the dynamic memory allocation for you, so you don't have to do it your self with `new`. All you need to do is `vector<int> foo;`. What is the point of `AddToVector` returning a bool when it always returns true?

Answer (score 1):

In `createNewVector`

```
vector<int> *vector1 = new vector<int>(n);
```

Created a `vector` with `n` default initialized values. These are `int`s, so that's 0s. This means with `n=5` the `vector` comes out of the constructor containing 5 0s and then the program pushes back 5,4,3,2,1, resulting in the given output.

The solution is get rid of the `n` in the constructor.

```
vector<int> *vector1 = new vector<int>();
```

If you are trying to save time by pre-allocating storage (Note: You will save an utterly insignificant, if any, amount of time doing this), you want

```
vector<int> *vector1 = new vector<int>();
vector1->reserve(5);
```

I use "you want" with some reservations. You don't want to dynamically allocate a `vector`. There are very few reasons where you want a dynamic `vector` and many reasons why you don't. Most important don't is probably because you've added a manual memory management requirement onto a class designed to eliminate manual memory management.